# Why is the 'identityProvider' claim missing in the ClaimsPrincipal running in an Azure Function v2?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, claims-based-identity

I have an Azure Function App that is deployed in 2 environments, one for Development and one Production, each with their own URL.

In both environments, the functions are configured to enable users to authenticate using their Facebook account. I actually configured 2 different Facebook applications: one for Development environment and one for the Production environment.

Here is the code of one Azure Function which simply logs in Application Insights all the headers of the HTTP request as well as all the claims of the injected `ClaimsPrincipal` instance:

```
public sealed class FindAccountFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger m_logger;

    public FindAccountFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        m_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FindAccountFunction>();
    }

    [FunctionName("FindAccount")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(
                AuthorizationLevel.Function,
                "get",
                Route = "v1/accounts"
            )]
            HttpRequest httpRequest,
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
     {
         // Logs all Headers of the httpRequest
         // Logs all the claims of claimsPrincipal.

         return new OkObjectResult("Ok");
     }
}
```

Everything works great in the Production environment because I can identify the user connected by getting the `nameidentifier` and the `identityprovider` claims, as seen in the following logs:

[image: Logs with stable_sid]

The problem appears in the Development environment. For some reason, I am getting a number as the `nameidentifier` (instead of an hexadecimal number starting with `sid:`) and the `identityprovider` is missing altogether from the claims:

[image: Logs without stable_sid]

**Question**

What can cause the `nameidentifier` to be a number in the Development environment and the `identityprovider` claim to be missing from the `ClaimsPrincipal` instance?

Is there any permissions that could be missing?

**Update**

I have added the [setting](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Understanding-User-Ids) `WEBSITE_AUTH_HIDE_DEPRECATED_SID` and set it to `true` in both environments.

Here is the JWT token from the Development environment:

```
{
  "sub": "sid:a3xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "idp": "facebook",
  "ver": "4",
  "iss": "https://dev.company.ca/",
  "aud": "https://dev.company.ca/",
  "exp": 1557524710,
  "nbf": 1552343212
}
```

Here is the JWT token from the Production environment:

```
{
  "sub": "sid:06afxxxxxxxx",
  "idp": "facebook",
  "ver": "4",
  "iss": "https://prod.company.ca/",
  "aud": "https://prod.company.ca/",
  "exp": 1557526156,
  "nbf": 1552342494
}
```

Still, the Development environment did not provide the expected `identityprovider` claim and the `nameidentifier` claim in the `ClaimsPrincipal` instance is different from the JWT's.

For now, as a workaround, I simply use the JWT to extract the `sid` but I would rather have the framework to provide me this.

**Update 2**

I have opened this as an [issue on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a breaking change that happened in summer '18, as specified in [the GitHub thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4212#issuecomment-480378690).

Here is the workaround to fix it:

> **Summary**
>
> The App Service Authentication/Authorization feature made a breaking
>   change for `X-ZUMO-AUTH` token behavior for apps that enabled EasyAuth
>   after mid-2018. That breaking change is being reverted in the next few
>   weeks.
>
> **Workaround**
>
> In the meantime, if you want your dev application behavior to match
>   your production application's behavior, you can do so by deleting the
>   "runtimeVersion" property in your site auth settings. You can do so
>   with the following.
>
> 1. Navigate to https://resources.azure.com/
> 2. Via the drop down menus on the side, navigate to `subscriptions > (subName) > resourceGroups > (resourceGroupName) > providers >
>      Microsoft.Web > sites > (siteName) > config > authSettings`.
> 3. Edit the `json` object under properties and set `runtimeVersion` to "".
> 4. Use the PUT operation to make those changes.
> 5. If these steps were successful you should see `runtimeVersion` no longer present in your application.
>
> NOTE: If you disable and then reenable Authentication/Authorization at
>   any point, it will add a value for "`runtimeVersion`", and you will have
>   to follow the above steps again to remove it.

Comment: The fix for this should be deployed for dedicated function apps, so hopefully the workaround is no longer necessary. Let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: @ConnorMcMahon Thanks for your help! :)